# How to implement custom mutating methods in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am writing a gem where I would like to implement a conditional assignment in a C extension.

The idea is provide assignment for [logical defined-or](https://github.com/mberlanda/logic_or). This would only assign if the variable is `nil`. For example...

```
var = false
var //= 42   # var is false
var = nil
var //= 23   # var is 23
```

I found in the `ruby/ruby` repository the definition of [abbreviated assignment](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e9adca495582c21d7d25efd1b6388f32911ca218/doc/syntax/assignment.rdoc#assignment-methods):

```
There are also ||= and &&=. The former makes an assignment if
the value was nil or false while the latter makes an assignment 
if the value was not nil or false.
```

I did not manage to find a reference in the source code. *(As referred in the comments below `||=` is not an operator but just syntax sugar)*

I tried to look on apidock.com the definition of some bang methods: e.g. [`Array#map!`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/map%21):

```
static VALUE
rb_ary_collect_bang(VALUE ary)
{
    long i;

    RETURN_ENUMERATOR(ary, 0, 0);
    rb_ary_modify(ary);
    for (i = 0; i < RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
        rb_ary_store(ary, i, rb_yield(RARRAY_PTR(ary)[i]));
    }
    return ary;
}
```

I managed to follow the references to `rb_ary_modify` and `rb_ary_store` in [`array.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e9adca495582c21d7d25efd1b6388f32911ca218/array.c).

Would you know how to implement a mutating method such as:

```
require 'logic_or'

# Current behaviour
nil.lor('a') # => "a"
false.lor('a') # => false

a = nil # => nil
a.lor('a') # => "a"
a # => nil

# Expected behaviour
a = nil # => nil
a.lor!('a') # => "a"
a # => "a"
```

**Update**

As pointed out in comments, the previous title (*How is Double pipe or equals (||=) implemented in ruby?*) was not coherent with the content of the question

Comment: Can you clarify your question, please? You are asking about assignment and about bang methods. Those two are completely unrelated and have nothing to do with each other. Assignment is a built-in language feature. Bang methods are simply a naming convention to distinguish two methods doing similar things.

Comment: I would like to implement a method changing the value of it`self`. I was considering both solution but I could not see how to implement them. Which approach would you suggest?

Comment: Neither a method nor an assignment can change the value of `self`. `self` is always the receiver of the message send.

Comment: Probably I did not find the right wording for expressing myself. Should I provide another example of the desired behavior is clear in the question?

Comment: When Ruby sees `a ||= b` she merely replaces it with `a = a || b` as a first step in parsing the expression. The same is true with the many other *abbreviated assignments* that are permitted. Think of it as a form of [syntactic sugar](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/lessons/ruby-shortcuts-and-syntactic-sugar).

Comment: hey @CarySwoveland, thank you very much! and could you redirect me to some resources for implementing ! methods?

Comment: For classes that have an instance method `replace` (e.g., `String`, `Array` and `Hash`), `class C; def m!(*args) replace(m(*args)) end; end`, where  (`replace(m(*args))` is the normal way of writing `self.replace(self.m(*args))`. Regardless of whether `replace` is available, there may of course be better ways to write the bang method.

Comment: Thank you again! There is any `replace` like implementation for nil class to implement what I was describing in the example?

Comment: That one is easy, since `NilClass` has a single instance, `nil` which is an [immediate value](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/faq/6/) (Note `Fixnum` is deprecated; substitute `Integer` at the link), so `class NilClass; def replace; nil; end; end`, but you don't need `replace`, because for any instance method of `NilClass`, there is need for a banged version, for it would not alter the receiver, `self #=> nil`. The same is true for all receivers that are immediate values (integers, `true` and so on).

Comment: If I understand correctly, this means that it is impossible to define a method that given `a = nil`, I will call `a.foo!("a")` and then `a # => "a"`? And the same for booleans and `Integer`s?

Comment: It is *still* not clear what you want to achieve. You write "Would you know how to implement a `!` method or a conditional reassignment of a variable disregarding of the `VALUE` type?" as if those two things were the same or at least somehow related, but as I explained above, they have nothing to do with each other. A bang method is literally a method whose name ends with `!`. You implement it like any other method. Here: `def foo!() 42 end`. That's a bang method. (It's not a *good* bang method, because a bang should only be used to mark the "more surprising" one of a *pair* of methods.)

Comment: hi @JörgWMittag thank you for getting back. I would like to implement a method that given `a = nil`, I can call `a.some_method(false)` and then `a` would be `false`. I am sorry I was not able to find a better way to explain so far. Would be useful to create a gist with a few tests to describe the behaviour?

Comment: @mabe02 Assuming this works like Perl's defined-or, I've added an example.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can implement `val //= 23`, which Perl refers to as "dor" (defined-or). There's no underlying method call. Instead, `val ||= 23` is compiled into...

```
if !val
  val = 23
end
```

`val //= 23` would be...

```
if val.nil?
  val = 23
end
```

You can [find the code for this in compile.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/compile.c#L6086). You'd have to somehow hack the parser to add a new `idDOROP` opcode and change the grammar. It's not impossible, it's done in Perl all the time, but it's very messy.

I also don't think you can do `val.dor(23)`. That would require assigning to `self` which isn't allowed.

```
class Object
  def dor(value)
    self = value if self.nil?
  end
end

Can't change the value of self
    self = value if self.nil?
```

Closest I can come up with is this.

```
class Object
  def dor(value)
    value if self.nil?
  end
end

obj = obj.dor(42)
puts obj
```

Which is a questionable improvement over...

```
obj = 42 if obj.nil?
puts obj
```

---

In general, `//=` is not necessary in Ruby. `//=` came about in Perl because Perl considers `0` and `""` to be false. There's many occasions where those are valid values but would be obliterated by `$var ||= $default`. People got tired of writing `$var = $default if !defined $var` and `//=` was born.

In Ruby there are only two false values, `nil` and `false`. Everything else is true. `var ||= default` will do the right thing with `0` and `""` so there's little need for `//=`.

If your design requires regularly distinguishing between `nil` and `false` often enough to write a new operator, change your design.

Comment: Hi @Schwern thank you very much! It may not be a good idea to mess up with `idDROP` unless it is a common practice in Ruby as well. I tried to implement as well a new operator but I could not find how to proceed (I saw `superators19` gem  which does not seem to work as expected for Ruby 2.x). In any case, I may just to accept that I cannot do more than what I did here: https://github.com/mberlanda/logic_or